# Rails: How to set Namespace CoffeeScript so a script is only called on given page(s)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parameters, coffeescript

I'm calling a Java/coffescript function, `typehandler` (not shown), repeatedly with slightly different parameters. This is happening on EVERY page load for the application. It really only needs to happen on the 3 or 4 pages where the script is applicable. AND, within those pages it should only be called twice given the appropriate parameters:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/disk_items.js.coffee
jQuery(document).ready ->
  typehandler = (selector, url, hidden_id, entry_id) ->
  ...    
## if page is DiskItem#edit
typehandler '.projects_tt', '/projects.json', '#disk_file_project_code', '#project_code'
typehandler '.products_tt', '/products.json', '#disk_file_product_id', '#product_title'
## if page is InventoryItem#edit_multiple
typehandler '.projects_tt', '/projects.json', '#inventory_item_project_code', '#project_code'
typehandler '.products_tt', '/products.json', '#inventory_item_product_id', '#product_title'
...
```

How can I:

1. only run the script on certain pages
2. set the 3rd parameter, `#disk_file_project_code`, given something from the page? Maybe an HTML `data` element OR perhaps it could pick up that `id` from within the form?

Answer (score 0):

Is embedding the function calls within the actual html page in a script tag undesirable?  Because that's probably the simplest way forward.

If that is seen as bad form, and/or the function call has to be within the js.coffee file itself for some reason, then you could check for your location with something like

```
if window.location.href.indexOf("DiskItem/edit") > -1
```

and pull the 3rd parameter from the html via a data attribute or form value as you had suggested.